# How can I shift an {itemize} list to the right?

Tags: lists, indentation, itemize

I am making an `{itemize}` list whose labels are so wide that they stick into the left margin:

```
\begin{itemize}  
\item[(MPT1)]...  
\item[(MPT2)]...  
\item[(MPT3)]...  
\end{itemize}
```

How can I shift the entire list to the right to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setitemize{fullwidth}
```

For `enumitem` package v3.0 and later, use

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setitemize{wide}
```

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I decided to load the `enumitem` package and use

```
\begin{enumerate}[labelindent=\parindent,leftmargin=*,label=(MPT\arabic*)]
\item ...
\item ...
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: This doesn't really deserve an answer, does it? Also, if @Leo's answer was of any help, you should accept his response which is probably the best way to thank him for the interest and time spent on your question.

Comment: @chl: I do agree with your second sentence. But I find it quite OK to post stuff like this as an answer to one's own question.

Comment: @Hendrik Ok, I just find that it would have been more courteous to also cite the responder that gave the right clue.

Comment: @chl: I agree 100%.

Comment: The *best* option in my opinion would be to edit your example either into Leo's answer or your question.