# Using enumerate with no indent

Tags: lists, indentation

I have a enumerated list that start on the left of the text margin. How can I remove this so the word "Step 1" start on the same left margin like the rest of the document?

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl} % A4 paper and 11pt font size
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text

\begin{enumerate} [label=Step \arabic{enumi}.,ref=Step \arabic{enumi}]
\item Step A
\item Step b
\item Step C
\item Step D
\end{enumerate}

\noindent
Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you do not intend to use enumerate? :)

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate: [How can I shift an `itemize` list to the right?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10352/5764)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are 3 possibilities:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl} % A4 paper and 11pt font size
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text

\begin{enumerate} [label=Step \arabic{enumi}.,ref=Step \arabic{enumi}, leftmargin=*]
\item Step A Step A Step A Step A Step A Step A Step A Step A Step A Step A Step A Step A Step A Step A Step A Step A
\item Step B
\item Step C
\item Step D
\end{enumerate}

\noindent
Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text

\begin{enumerate} [label=Step \arabic{enumi}.,ref=Step \arabic{enumi}, wide=0pt]
\item Step A Step A Step A Step A Step A Step A Step A Step A Step A Step A Step A Step A Step A Step A Step A Step A
\item Step B
\item Step C
\item Step D
\end{enumerate}

\noindent
Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text

\begin{enumerate} [label=Step \arabic{enumi}.,ref=Step \arabic{enumi}, align=left]
\item Step A Step A Step A Step A Step A Step A Step A Step A Step A Step A Step A Step A Step A Step A Step A Step A
\item Step B
\item Step C
\item Step D
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Unclear, what is meant really, I applied `leftmargin=*` here:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl} % A4 paper and 11pt font size
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text

\begin{enumerate}[label={Step \arabic{enumi}}.,ref={Step \arabic{enumi}},leftmargin=*]
\item Step A
\item Step b
\item Step C
\item Step D
\end{enumerate}

\noindent

Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text

\end{document}
```

[image]