# suftesi: enumeration labels are outside of page margin

Tags: enumerate, suftesi

I use the `suftesi` package and observe that labels of lists are outside of the typeblock margin.

minimal example:

```
\documentclass[structure=collection]{suftesi}
\begin{document}    
    \noindent Just enough text to make the line break so we get to see a second line.
    enough text to make the line break so we get to see a second line
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item[A] An item
        \item[B] An item
        \item[C] An item 
    \end{enumerate}
    Just enough text to make the line break so we get to see a second line.
    enough text to make the line break so we get to see a second line
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item An item
    \item An item
    \item An item 
    \end{enumerate}
    Just enough text to make the line break so we get to see a second line.
    enough text to make the line break so we get to see a second line
\end{document}
```

[image]

what must be done to have the labels align or indent by a small amount (as is usual in other document classes?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311667/using-enumerate-with-no-indent

Comment: That's a precise stylistic choice made by the class.

Comment: And page 14 of the class documentation lists three options for list layout...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a precise stylistic choice (also Bringhurst does the same in his book on typography).

You can do differently by using the `liststyle` option, see section 3.6 in the manual.

```
\documentclass[
  structure=collection,
  liststyle=indented,
]{suftesi}

\begin{document}    

Just enough text to make the line break so we get to see a second line.
enough text to make the line break so we get to see a second line
\begin{enumerate}
  \item[A] An item
  \item[B] An item
  \item[C] An item 
\end{enumerate}
Just enough text to make the line break so we get to see a second line.
enough text to make the line break so we get to see a second line
\begin{enumerate}
  \item An item
  \item An item
  \item An item 
\end{enumerate}
Just enough text to make the line break so we get to see a second line.
enough text to make the line break so we get to see a second line

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you - I did read the manual, but then did not make the connection to `liststyle`.